# C++ Quicksort index 0 returns -842150451

Tags: c++

Basic quicksort function that partitions and has myswap. everything works fine except for index 0 in the array.

```
 #include<iostream>
 #include<string>
 #include<iostream>
 #include<vector>
 #include <ctime>

using namespace std;

//swap
void myswap(int mya[], int a, int b) {
int temp = mya[a];
mya[a] = mya[b];
mya[b] = temp;
}

//partition, returns pivot index
int mypartition(int mya[], int first, int last)
{
    int middle = ((first + last) / 2);
    int pivot = mya[middle];
    //swap first with middle
    myswap(mya, first, middle);
    //two pointers
    int pivotindex = first;
    //loop through the elements
    for (int index = first + 1; index <= last; index++) {
        if (mya[index] <= pivot)
        {
            pivotindex++;
            myswap(mya, pivotindex, index);
        }
    }
    //swap the pivot in its right place
    myswap(mya, first, pivotindex);
    return pivotindex;
}



void QuickSort(int mya[], int a, int b)
{
    //partition
    if (a <= b)
    {
        int index = mypartition(mya, a, b);
        QuickSort(mya, a, index - 1);
        QuickSort(mya, index + 1, b);
    }
}



int main() {
    //vector<int> mya;
    int * mya = new int[5000000];
srand(time(0));
int i = 0;
int last = 0;
while(i < 100)
{
    int x = (rand() + time(0)) % 5000000;
    mya[last] = x;
    last++;
    i++;
}

clock_t startTime, endTime;
startTime = clock();
QuickSort(mya, 0, last);
endTime = clock();
    cout << "Sorted in " << (double)(endTime - startTime) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC     << "      seconds" << endl;
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    cout << mya[i] << endl;
}
delete[] mya;
return 0;

}
```

The problem im having is that the array gets sorted but when mya[0] is called in the for loop it outputs -842150451. This is just a basic quicksort and for some reason im having trouble with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling it wrong.

```
QuickSort(mya, 0, last-1);
```

Remember that there are `last` elements, meaning they are indexed 0..last-1.

You do also have a potential overflow problem with your calculation of `middle`. Use `(last - first + 1)/2 + first`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. One more question. How long should this take to run? because at the moment it takes me about 15-20 seconds. if i run it with cpp.sh its instant but if i use visual studios it takes longer.

Comment: @NickPeterson it shouldn't take long at all. You're only sorting a hundred elements. If you really pushed yourself, you could do that *by hand* in 15-20 seconds. Your IDE is probably bending you over with its debugging and memory requirements. [See here for simplified run, sorting a million slots](http://ideone.com/VCbBc0). Best of luck.

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention I was using 5 million elements.

Answer (score 1):

Integer Overflow Causing this problem.

`int x = (rand() + time(0)) % 5000000;`

this line sometime two 10 digits long numbers whose sum is causing the integer overflow.

Just modify that statement as following and your code starts working:

`int x = (rand() % 5000000) + (time(0) % 5000000);`

Edit: It was a problem I found executing your code using Ideone. Further noticing I found Your Index 0 problem is actually caused by partition function.

change `for (int index = first + 1; index <= last; index++) {` this line to

`for (int index = first + 1; index < last; index++) { //remove the equal sign`

N.B: for me this fixed your issue. But I think in your `void QuickSort(int mya[], int a, int b)`

`if (a <= b)` should be changed to `if (a < b)`.

Comment: That didn't seem to change anything. It happens with smaller numbers too.

Comment: I actually figured it out. in the main function i was calling last, where I should have been calling last - 1. Thanks for all your help tho much appreciated.